# EE Entry will not save when Playa relationship is searched for relationship

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic

The most bizarre thing has just started: When either creating or updating an entry with a playa field and I use the built-in playa search for the relationship, the EE entry will not save (returns to CP).

BUT, when i scroll through the relationships and select the related entry (without touching anything else) the EE entry will save.

This just began happening. EE 2.7 Playa 4.4.5

Any thoughts on why this would be occurring?

Comment: Same thing happen if you try other browsers to do the edit?

Comment: Yes, I have tried IE10, Firefox, Chrome and Safari on both a PC and a Mac and get the same results.